# jQuery Steps Remove Action Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-steps

I'm using the jQuery steps plugin to break down large forms into manageable steps but I want to remove the action buttons (next, previous, finish etc) I have enabled the

```
enableAllSteps
```

attribute so the users can navigate the form this way instead. I've disabled the finish button via the

```
enableFinishButton
```

option but can not find anything in the documentation for the other action buttons. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Steps [settings](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings) there is the field:

> `enablePagination`    Enables pagination (next, previous and finish button)
>   if true.  By default it is `true`

Comment: perfect thank you, the 'action' buttons seems to be called a few different names through out the app, actions, pagination, buttons so its hard to follow without there being consistency

Comment: Let's hope that the author will read this and will take this into account in future versions of this great plugin.